# iOS - Open file with specific program

Tags: ios, pdf

I have a pdf file that I would like to open with a specific app, like iBooks. I would like to have it so that the user can set what program they want to open it with among the ones currently installed that can handle it. Here is the code I have that lets me do just that, only the user has to select which app to use each time (an extra step I'd like to avoid):

```
NSString *stringVariable = cell.textLabel.text;

NSString *homeDir = NSHomeDirectory();
homeDir = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@", homeDir, @"Documents"];  
NSString * filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", homeDir, stringVariable]; 

documentController = 
[UIDocumentInteractionController 
interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
documentController.delegate = self;
[documentController retain];
documentController.UTI = @"com.adobe.pdf";
[documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero 
                                       inView:self.view 
                                     animated:YES];
```

So stringVariable contains the name of the document in question, and then it displays the various apps capable of running it. If I could somehow populate that into a selector of some kind so the user can select the default app to use, that would be great, but if I have to settle for setting it to a specific app myself (like iBooks), that would work too.

Comment: I too would like to know how to 'force' a selection. I want to open files from my app with certain other apps - however I do not want to let the user open the file with something like 'dropbox' and save a copy of my file.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way at this point. I've looked around too.

Comment: I just asked Apple Tech support about this and they have replied it is not possible at the moment (just after iOS 6 released)

Answer (score 0):

Use UTI param. For instance, if you have 5 apps that support Instagram url scheme and file types, just use this:

```
documentController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
```

It will not make the selection for you, but it will limit the choice to the app want.

Comment: I know, I included that line up there. I was already at that point, but I wanted to get it where you can choose the app you want. I have heard from apple themselves that it is not possible.